# how to scroll item inside webelement using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

we know how to scroll page with selenium like by calling execute
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-600);")
but let say i want to scroll[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ9Mf.png)

you can see in the image above that what I want to achieve is to scroll that orange scroll bar so all my contact can be loaded and then I scrape the info which I need it is needed in many websites where data is inside some scroll view like WhatsApp contact list. so how I achieve automatic scrolling with python selenium I try

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('nano-slider')[3].scrollTop=100;")
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 
action  = ActionChains(driver)
slider = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("nano-slider")[3]
action.move_to_element(slider).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(0,100).perform()
```

as I see during the writing of this question scroll comes exactly what I need to scroll with python selenium automation

Comment: that element interface doesn't have scrollBy and your action class work aroound works , what were you looking for other than taht ?

Comment: what I think is to execute the js like by first clicking on that scroll and make it scroll downwards with some sort of code which I am not getting